# WSO2 esb processor send message to queue and other processor receive specific message from queue

Tags: queue, processor, wso2-esb

WSO2 esb:
 (in Api)processor1 send message to queue and other processor2 wait for specific message to get it. Is it possible that processor2 wait for specific message, if found then send to destination?
[this is flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuwcY.png)

Comment: Is it a question you are asking or a statement ? , Please follow the link and check if you are facing any issues , https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Adding+a+Message+Processor

Comment: thanks for above info but message has to be stored in queue. Moreover is there any way where receiving processor can wait till pick a specific message from queue (like id=5)

Comment: Create a proxy and mention the parameter as "<parameter name="transport.jms.MessageSelector">id='5'</parameter>" , Try and let me know whether this is working or not